# Use of ADC Bits below noise floor

Tags: adc, accuracy

I have a Sigma Delta Modulator with a SINC3 Filter. The System runs at maximum oversampling possible for this application and I know my (Full Scale Signal)ENOB for this szenario to be 14.

Is there any reason NOT to truncate Bits below thath threshold? The Target is a FPGA so keeping 2 more bits because a C variable is 16 bits large is no reason either. My guts says there must be some reason to at least keep "No missing Code" Bits, but I find no explanation other than maybe truncation adds some weird bias to a signed value or that I just dont want to surrender accuracy that wasn't actually there in the first place.

Are there any reasons to keep Bits below the noise floor, when further oversampling is not possible?

Comment: Have you heard of dithering?

Answer (score 3):

Some systems operate with negative SNR (negative in dB, less than 1.0 in linear units).  That's because uncorrelated noise is rejected at some point in the signal path, so that only a small fraction of the noise actually interferes with the signal.

If you are implementing despreading, it will be essential to keep some "below the noise floor" bits.